# Sorting array of XYZ coordinates into table in Python

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and I can't figure out how to solve this problem.
I have an array with lots of X,Y,Z coordinates and I need to create an output file to import them to exel.

I imported an STL file and put created an 2D array from that file

Right now the array is like this:

```
example = [[X1,Y1,Z1],[X1,Y2,Z2],[X2,Y1,Z3],[X2,Y2,Z4]]
```

The X and Y coordinates repeat themselves alot and the z is always different.

What I need to do is to sort them with this layout to save it to an .csv file:

```
example, Y1, Y2
X1, Z1, Z2
X2, Z3, Z4
```

so put the X coordinates as rows, the Y columns and the Z in its corresponding place 
Can any help me out with this?
Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: It's unclear what the rule is to get the output from the input? Also, what type of output you're looking for: another Python structure, printing to screen, etc?  Also, is your input list really longer than shown, or is it just these 12 items?

Comment: Hi, sorry I should give more info.
The output file is a .csv file to open in exel. so every row is a row in exel and every "," is a column in exel. 
The array is huge, the example above is just the way I though it would be the best way to explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break this problem up into the following steps:

1. Get all the unique x and y coordinates
2. Construct a table/matrix of the appropriate size
3. Assign the `x` and `y` coordinates along the top and left edges
4. Iterate through the array, grab the `z` coordinate, and map it to the correct location in the matrix according to the its `x` and `y` coordinates
5. Output the resulting matrix as a csv file.

I'm making the following assumptions:

1. If a given `x, y, z` coordinate does not exist in the array, but has a space available for it within the matrix, the corresponding spot in the matrix will have the value "0"
2. There are no duplicate coordinates within the array.

Given these assumptions, the following program should roughly do what I think you want.

```
def find_x_and_y(array):
    '''Step 1: Get unique x and y coordinates, 
    and the width and height of the matrix'''
    x = sorted(list(set([i[0] for i in array])))
    y = sorted(list(set([i[1] for i in array])))

    width = len(x) + 1
    height = len(y) + 1

    return x, y, width, height

def construct_initial_matrix(array):
    '''Step 2: Make the initial matrix (filled with zeros)'''
    x, y, width, height = find_x_and_y(array)

    matrix = []
    for i in range(height):
        matrix.append([0] * width)

    return matrix

def add_edging(array, matrix):
    '''Step 3: Add the x and y coordinates to the edges'''
    x, y, width, height = find_x_and_y(array)

    for coord, position in zip(x, range(1, height)):
        matrix[position][0] = coord

    for coord, position in zip(y, range(1, width)):
        matrix[0][position] = coord

    return matrix

def add_z_coordinates(array, matrix):
    '''Step 4: Map the coordinates in the array to the position
    in the matrix'''
    x, y, width, height = find_x_and_y(array)

    x_to_pos = dict(zip(x, range(1, height)))
    y_to_pos = dict(zip(y, range(1, width)))

    for x, y, z in array:
        matrix[x_to_pos[x]][y_to_pos[y]] = z
    return matrix

def make_csv(matrix):
    '''Step 5: Pretty-printing'''
    return '\n'.join(', '.join(str(i) for i in row) for row in matrix)

def main():
    #example = [[1, 1, 10], [1, 2, 11], [2, 1, 12], [2, 2, 13]]
    example = [[1000,250,12.2],[1000,500,10],[2000,250,15],[2000,500,13.5]]

    matrix = construct_initial_matrix(example)
    matrix = add_edging(example, matrix)
    matrix = add_z_coordinates(example, matrix)

    print make_csv(matrix)

main()
```

Comment: Uau it looks alot more complicated then I was expecting :) I will try to figure it out, I'm sure I will have hours of trail and error with your post, but I think I can make sense of it. Thank you so much for your replay

Comment: I can't make it work, keep getting the same error over and over: range() integer end argument expected, got float.
can't figure out whats the problem.

Comment: @user2725701 Are the coordinates floating point numbers? I'm assumed that they're integers. If they are floating point numbers, could you edit your question to include a snippit of about 10 or so actual coordinates in the array, and the expected output if the array were that short?

Comment: sorry I'm really new to pytho, had no idea what a float was had to study for a bit. ok so yes it has float numbers but the x and y can be converted to integers only the z's have to be floats. which is ok in the code you wrote.

Comment: now what doesn't work is the spaces between each one as 0 because the coordinates go like this more or less: [[1000,250,12.2],[1000,500,10],[2000,250,15],[2000,500,13.5]] etc. having 0 in the z's input in the matrix is ok but adding the columns and row like it is now will not work

Comment: @user2725701 -- Ah, I see. I went ahead and edited my answer. It should work now given the new requirements. It should also in theory work for floating point numbers for the x and y coordinates, although you should test that out first to make sure it really works.

Comment: great it work, thanks so much that is awesome. I see how you did it, i was trying something like that, but got stuck in adding the x and y to the rows and columns by order. thank you again. AMAZING

Comment: @user2725701 No problem! If the answer worked for you, click the check mark next to my answer to let others know that your problem was solved.